# Вызов асинхронной функции по таймеру в C#

Tags: c#, async-await

Можно ли как-нибудь вызвать по таймеру асинхронную функцию в C#? У обычного `System.Threading.Timer` callback-функция не может быть асинхронной, но, может, существуюут какие-нибудь другие способы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С таймером и асинхронными методами надо быть аккуратнее. Как вы верно заметили, `Timer` не поддерживает асинхронные методы, а потому предложенный в другом ответе способ естественно имеет недостатки. `TimerCallback` -- это `void`-метод, т.е. по сути вы передаете `async void` метод. Отсюда два следствия:

1. Таймер *не будет* дожидаться завершения функции, что может
   привести к нежелательным последствиям (например, вызовы будут
   накладываться друг на друга).
2. Поскольку метод не ожидается, то и об исключениях в нем тоже
   никто не узнает. Обязательно нужно обрабатывать ошибки в самом
   методе, иначе исключение в пуле потоков может привести к завершению
   приложения (впрочем, этот пункт относится и к синхронным делегатам).

Встроенной поддержки регулярного запуска асинхронной функции в .NET пока нет. Самый простой вариант - написать метод с использованием бесконечного цикла и `Task.Delay`. Это по-настоящему асинхронный вариант периодического запуска асинхронного метода. Код может выглядеть так:

```
public async Task RunPeriodicallyAsync(
    Func<Task> func,
    TimeSpan interval,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        await Task.Delay(interval, cancellationToken)
        await func();
    }
}
```

Сюда по желанию/необходимости можно добавлять обработку ошибок, `ConfigureAwait(false)` и все, что еще понадобится.

Answer (score 2):

В `Timer` можно передать асинхронный делегат, в коде выглядеть это будет так:

```
System.Threading.Timer timer = new Timer(async state =>
{
    await Task.Delay(500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Я у себя в коде под Андроид сделал так:

```
    _timerUniversal = new Timer(CheckUniversal, _startTime, 0, TimerWait);
    async Task<int> CallAll()
    {
        await CheckNewUserCallback();
        await CheckNewGroupCallback();
        await CheckNewMessagesCallback();
        await WriteMessagesFromChannels();
        await AddChannelUsers();

        return 1;
    }

    void CheckUniversal(object state)
    {
        var rc = CallAll();
    }
```

Не знаю, насколько это правильно, но, вроде, работает.

Comment: Здесь по-прежнему `async void` вместе с "fire and forget". Вы не ожидаете `CallAll`().